# .NET Core Reference Type project not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-core

I am having trouble with project reference and .NET Core.

I have a library (`MyLib`) in the src folder and two project in the test folder (`MyLib.Tests` and `MyLib.Tests.Support`)

Summarized:

```
|-- global.json
|-- src
|   \-- MyLib
\-- test
    |-- MyLib.Tests
    \-- MyLib.Tests.Support
```

MyLib is already available through NuGet and the tests projects are not (and won't be).

When I reference (with the `right click > add reference` option) `MyLibTest.Support` within `MyLib.Tests`, the `dotnet-restore` works fine. In visual studio, under "References", I have the small icon indicating it is a project reference. When I reference (still with the `right click > add reference` option) `MyLib` within `MyLib.Tests`, the `dotnet-restore` works also fine but I have the small icon indicating it is a nuget reference.

It is the expected behaviour but I don't want my test project to test the "old" NuGet package but the actual code.

According to the documention and a lots of tutorial I found on the internet, I then configure in `MyLib.Tests\project.json` the `MyLib` dependency as a project dependency:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
      "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
      "SimpleDao": {
        "target": "project"
        "version": "2.0.0-*"
      },
      "MyLib.Tests.Support": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

But then, the `dotnet-restore` fails:

1. Visual Studio error: `NU1001 The dependency MyLib could not be resolved.`
2. Console error: `Unable to resolve 'MyLib' for '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6'`

Here is my global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Ask me for anything else that could be relevant to explain my troubles

Thanks in advance.
(Excuse me for my english, I am not a native speaker)

---

**Edit:**

I realized there is also something wrong with my lib : actually `MyLib` is composed of three libs:

1. `MyLib`, mostly interfaces, targetting `.netstandard1.1`
2. `MyLib.Impl1`, first implementation, targetting `.net451` and `.netstandard1.3` (not yet on NuGet)
3. `MyLib.Impl2`, second implementation, targetting `.net45` (there is already a first version of it on NuGet)

Always with the same methodology for adding the reference (`right click > add reference`). **I did not edit the project.json files** (both are adding the reference like this: "MyLib": "2.0.0-*").

In the first implementation, visual studio get the dependencies through NuGet (there is the NuGet icon in the references tab). And I do not have the lastest edit on the interfaces of MyLib.

In the second implementation, visual studio get the dependencies within the project (there is the project icon in the references tab), and I do have the lastest edit on the interfaces.

If I try to edit the project.json to configure the dependency to MyLib as a project dependency, I can not restore the package too, same error than for the tests...

Is it a bug in .NET Core (I am trying to restore with both Visual Studio and dotnet-cli) or am I doing Something wrong?

**Edit 3:** I had published pre-release version of `MyLib` and `MyLib.Impl2` on NuGet. I deleted those version and get back to my solution. Now, `MyLib.Impl1` and `MyLib.Impl2` are targetting correctly my project reference (for `MyLib.Impl1` I had to specify the target in the project.json and not for `MyLib.Impl2`. I don't know why but at least it works now -_-).

But I still can't fix my test project. It still don't want to work with the project reference...

---

**Edit 2:**

[Here](https://github.com/fharr/SimpleDAO/tree/migration) is my github repository where you can find my whole code (within the migration branch).

Comment: What happens if you remove the `"version": "2.0.0-*"` line and only leave `"target": "project"` there?

Comment: It is the same. In the console line, the error is: `Unable to resolve 'MyLib' for '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6'` (I will edit my intial post to add this). Indeed, `MyLib` is targetting netstandard1.1 (in order to be .NET 4.5 compatible) but it should not be a problem. Everything written in netstandard1.1 is compatible with newer version...

Comment: Even if I change `MyLib.Tests` to target `netstandard1.1`, I get the same error.

Comment: I found out other problems of the same kind in the lib architecture ... I just edited my post with the new discoveries!

Comment: Do you mean you have pack the MyLib as NuGet package? Please explain what's mean of "MyLib is already available through NuGet "? If possible, please share a sample solution here to help us reproduce your issue.

Comment: MyLibrary is currently available on NuGet as a full .NET package and I am porting it to .NET Core. I will commit my port on github and give you the link so you can see by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a tough one ...

I was porting my lib from full .NET to .NET Core and during the process, I misnamed one project (upper/lower case issue). I renamed it with the right case but I didn't change anything in the .sln.

When I added this project as a reference in another project, Visual Studio was using the olg unchanged name from the .sln and not the current one.

It looks like it was easier to find the reference on NuGet than on local projects when there is a case issue like this ...